# React JS, can't write nested array inside prop to console

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-props

I have consumed a 3rd party API and saved the response to a state, then I passed an object in the response as a prop to another component.

This is the prop.

```
{
  "count": 20,
  "games": [
    {
      "id": 66947,
      "game_title": "Zelda 64: Dawn & Dusk",
      "release_date": "2019-09-22",
      "platform": 3,
      "developers": [
        6043
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 49433,
      "game_title": "Zelda II - The Adventure of Link",
      "release_date": "2013-09-12",
      "platform": 38,
      "developers": [
        6037
      ]
    },

    ....etc...

  ]
}
```

I can't figure out how to access the "games" data by mapping through it. So I thought I would try just simply writing the values to the console to see if I am making a silly mistake somewhere. If I write the prop to console with this code.

```
console.log(this.props.searchResults);
```

It writes everything to the console just like you would expect. However if try to write the games array with this code I get an error.

```
console.log(this.props.searchResults.games);
```

This is the error.

`TypeError: this.props.searchResults is undefined`

What I am ultimately doing is trying to do is map through the games array and render the titles in the browser, but if I can't even write the titles in the console then I obviously have a problem. I am new to both javascript and react so I am pretty sure there is just something simple I am missing about iterating through an object key whose value is an array.

One other thing I tried was sending the "games" array to the component in the first place but I am running into the same issue.

Comment: Maybe your this.props.searchResults is undefined at some point? What if you add a check to make sure this.props.searchResults is defined before accessing the games? Something like: if (!!this.props.searchResults) {console.log(this.props.searchResults.games);}

Comment: Run console.log(this,props.searchResults.count) and see if that works

Comment: @recidplayer before passing to other component do console and check value is there or undefined... can you share your code in sandbox?

Comment: @NickG That worked and got the games array to write to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be related to promise. Since you are able to log the prop in console, it means you are not making any silly mistake. When you make an api call and set that as a state. There's always a delay until promise gets resolved so the component will just get searchResult as null. So, what you need to do is wait for the data to be fetched. Easiest way can be like this:

```
Class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchResults: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    // Load data from api here
    this.setState({searchResults: {games: 'just replace this whole setState with your response data' }})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <ChildComponent searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now in your child component you can simply do this:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {searchResults} = this.props;
    return searchResults.games ? (
      <div>
      {
        // Your logic here to use searchResults.games
      }
      </div>
    ): <div>Loading</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I just had to alter it to ```return searchResults ? ( ... ```